# charts_flutter how to change selection colour

Tags: flutter, dart, charts

How do I change the default selection color of the bar chart?

[image]

It seems to be adding dark shade to the the colour provided in the colorFn.

```
    behaviors: [
      charts.SelectNearest(),
      charts.DomainHighlighter()
    ],
    selectionModels: [
      charts.SelectionModelConfig(
        type: charts.SelectionModelType.info,            
        changedListener: (model) {              
          if (model.selectedDatum.isNotEmpty) {
            print(model.selectedDatum.first.datum.time);
          }
        },
      ),
    ],
```

Comment: havent found a way to do this with this library so switched to fl_chart which seem to be more robust